# What is the correct pattern for creating a header navigation across the app?

Tags: ios, ios5

I have been googling around, and I found some suggestions to use UINavigationController and sometimes the UITabBarController also makes sense (but to a lesser degree).

I never used a UINavigationController ...I just tried to and when I dragged it to the storyboard, it put two screens on the storyboard (a navigation controller connecting to a UITableView).  So I think this isn't what I actually needed.

Can someone please help me understand what I need to do to make a header navigation that is persistent across all the screens? In it I want to have sections like:

```
Home | Section1 | Section2 | Section3
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to consider what the user will see as the "meaning" of the structure you use.

The sense of a navigation controller is as a container that lets you show a sequence of content controllers where actions on one of them lead logically to the next.  The sense of a tab bar controller is of (mostly) unrelated content controllers that co-exist and don't have (much) dependence on each other.

I think it's good to start with the purpose of the interface rather than the appearance.

Comment: well, from your explanation, the tab bar controller seems like the thing that is closest to the navigation people are used to on the web.  Its basically for jumping to different sections of the app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna suggest to you something that helped me a lot, which is to go download Stanford's iPhone and iPad Development course CS193P from iTunes U (you go in iTunes Store, search for it and download it).

Secondly, you shouldn't ask such general questions on SO, the question you asked is something you can find out on your own by researching, reading [Apple's developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com), or doing a tutorial as I just suggested. Best of luck.